# Responsive Arrays in Styled Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, css-in-js

In Styled System, they have [Responsive Props](https://styled-system.com/responsive-styles). For example:

```
<Box width={['100%', '50%', '25%']} />
```

That will produce the following CSS:

```
.Box-hash {
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .Box-hash {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 52em) {
  .Box-hash {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

As an alternative, one could use the following syntax:

```
<Box width={{ _: '100%', md: '50%', lg: '25%' }} />
```

It will produce the same result.

I am wondering if is possible to do something similar with Styled Components.  What I have in mind is something like this:

```
const StyledBox = styled.div`

  width: ${['100%', '50%', '25%']};
`

const OtherStyledBox = styled.div`

  width: ${{ _: '100%', md: '50%', lg: '25%' }};
`
```

Is this possible with Styled Components?  If not, any idea how one would go about creating a function or 'mixin' that could do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your app's style "API" is to have 3 media query breakpoints, then you can use props within your styled-components and return the correct CSS. Specify the API you want, i.e. `<StyledBox width={{ _: '100%', md: '50%', lg: '25%' }} />`.

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

const StyledBox = styled.div`
  ${props => props.width && css`
    width: ${width._};

    @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
      width: ${width.md};
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 52em) {
      width: ${width.lg};
    }
  `}
`;

StyledBox.propTypes = {
  width: PropTypes.shape({
    _: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    md: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    lg: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }),
};

StyledBox.defaultProps = {
  width: {
    _: '100%',
    md: '50%',
    lg: '25%'
  }
};
```

Styled-component [css helper](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css) function

Usage:

```
<StyledBox>
  This gets default media breakpoints, 100%, 50%, 25%
</StyledBox>

<StyledBox
  width={{ _: '90%', md: '80%', lg: '70%'}}
>
  This gets overridden media breakpoints, 90%, 80%, 70%
</StyledBox>
```

**Update**

If you'd prefer **NOT** to write out the media query each time, factor it into a style utility function to be used in any other styled component you want to be responsive.

```
const mediaQueries = ({ sm = '100%', md = '50%', lg = '25%'}) => css`
  width: ${sm};

  @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
    width: ${md};
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 52em) {
    width: ${lg};
  }
`;
```

Then in *any* styled component import and use

```
const ResponsiveDiv = styled.div`
  ...

  ${mediaQueries()}

  ...
`;

const CustomResponsiveDiv = styled.div`
  ...

  ${mediaQueries({ _: '90%', md: '80%', lg: '70%'})}

  ...
`;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Just to be clear, I do NOT want to create a prop that accepts the responsive array or object.  Rather, I want to place the array or object within the style definition itself.  I don't want to have to keep writing out `@media (min-width: ...) {...}`.

Comment: @Moshe Extract the functionality into a utility. Updated to include usage as a utility function. Hopefully more to what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks again -- this is definitely closer.  And please don't feel obligated to do another update.  But what I am looking for is something that can work with any css property.  'width', 'font-size', 'display', etc.  It seems to me that this works just for the 'width' property.  I'll see if I can rework it - it certainly sends me in the right direction -- thanks for that :).

Comment: @Moshe Glad it is at least getting your closer. Would a function signature like this be better? `const createMediaQueries = (cssRule: string, { sm = 'initial', md = 'initial', lg = 'initial'})` Takes a (any) rule and value object, and creates the media queries for you. Or are you thinking you already have all the breakpoints **AND** the rule values for them previously defined, say, like in a theme file, and then a function could look like `const addMediaQueries(cssRules: string[])` that takes the array of rules you want media queries created for?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the EmotionJS library [Facepaint](https://github.com/emotion-js/facepaint).  With that library, I can do the following:

```
const mq = facepaint([
  '@media(min-width: 480px)',
  '@media(min-width: 768px)',
  '@media(min-width: 992px)',
  '@media(min-width: 1200px)',
  '@media(min-width: 1600px)',
])

const Test = styled.div`
  background-color: orange;

  ${mq({
    width: ['10px', '25px', '50px', '100px', '200px', '400px'],
    height: ['10px', '25px', '50px', '100px', '200px', '400px'],
  })};
`
```

This is basically what I want to do.  At the moment I don't know how to create an object systax -- i.e.,:  `width: { _: '15px', md: '30px', xl: '100px' }`.  But for now it is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

I built a media query helper that allows you to put an array inside backticks like this:

```html
mq`
    width: ${[300, 600, 900]};
    color: ${["red", "blue"]};
    background-color: white;
`
```

Learn more:
https://github.com/hadiab/styled-easy-mq